# While creating theme, RGBA color code is automatically converting into Hexa Code

Tags: css

I am using SVG data image as my menu Icon. Where I am using "stroke='rgba(247,77,77,1)'" as the color for the icon. Problem what I am facing is that the stoke color code is automatically converting into hexa code (#F74D4D) once I build a theme, due to which the icon is not appearing in my application.

Can someone please let me know why the conversion is happening.

```css
#keyword div {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(247,77,77,1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}
```

```html
<figure id="keyword">
  <div></div>

</figure>
```

Comment: Actually `rgba(247,77,77,1)'` is exactly `#F74D4D` (sort of red).

Comment: Add a height to the `div` and your background image appears. Are you sure this is a problem with color conversion?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is stroke is not accepting '#F74D4D' as color code, and we always set the color code as RGBA format.

Comment: The problem is not with the conversion. It seems the declaration of the svg is wrong. You have some special symbols. The declaration should be something like: `<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... > ... </svg>'>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to encode the `()` to `%28` and `%29` and add a height

```css
#keyword div {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba%28247,77,77,1%29' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height:32px;
}
```

```html
<figure id="keyword">
  <div></div>
</figure>
```